# Absolutely Minimizing Lipschitz extension

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mg.metric-geometry

Is there an analytical or even numerical way to find the Absolutely Minimizing Lipschitz extension of a given function?
I know that the extension exist and it is unique  (by Aronsson et al).

I found two schemes by Adam Oberman [2](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-12/S0002-9939-08-09457-4/S0002-9939-08-09457-4.pdf) and [3](http://www.jointmathematicsmeetings.org/mcom/2005-74-251/S0025-5718-04-01688-6/S0025-5718-04-01688-6.pdf).
But the first is not realy Absolutely Minimizing
and the second is feasible only in very low euclidean dimension

Is there anything better?